# Скрипт создания миниатюр из изображений

Tags: mysql, php, html, css, база-данных

```
<?php
if ($_POST) {
    $f_err     = 0; //вспомогательная переменная
    $types     = array(
        '.jpg',
        '.JPG',
        '.jpeg',
        '.gif',
        '.bmp',
        '.png'
    ); //поддерживаемые форматы         загружаемых файлов
    $max_size  = 5020500; //максимальный размер загружаемого файла (5000 Кило)
    $fname     = md5($fname) . $ext;
    $path      = 'avatar/full/' . $username . "_" . $fname; //директория для загрузки
    $path_mini = 'avatar/thumb/'; //директория для загрузки миниатюры
    $fname     = $_FILES['file']['name'];
    $ext       = substr($fname, strpos($fname, '.'), strlen($fname) - 1); //определяем тип загружаемого   файла
    
    //проверка на соответствие формата
    if (!in_array($ext, $types)) {
        $f_err++;
        $mess = '<p style="color:red;">Загружаемый файл не является картинкой</p>';
    }
    
    //проверка размера файла
    if (filesize($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']) > $max_size) {
        $f_err++;
        $mess = '<p style="color:red;">Размер загружаемой картинки превышает 5 Mb</p>';
    }
    
    //если файл успешно прошел проверку
    //перемещаем его в заданную директорию из временной
    if ($f_err == 0) {
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $path . $fname);
        
        //путь к загруженному файлу
        $source_src = $path . $fname;
        
        //создаем путь и имя миниатюры
        $new_name     = md5($fname) . $ext;
        $resource_src = $path_mini . $username . "_" . $new_name;
        
        //получаем параметры загруженного файла
        $params = getimagesize($source_src);
        
        switch ($params[2]) {
            case 1:
                $source = imagecreatefromgif($source_src);
                break;
            case 2:
                $source = imagecreatefromjpeg($source_src);
                break;
        }
        
        //если высота больше ширины
        //вычисляем новую ширину
        if ($params[1] > $params[0]) {
            $newheight = 500;
            $newwidth  = floor($newheight * $params[0] / $params[1]);
        }
        //если ширина больше высоты
        //вычисляем новую высоту
        if ($params[1] < $params[0]) {
            $newwidth  = 500;
            $newheight = floor($newwidth * $params[1] / $params[0]);
        }
        
        //создаем миниатюру загруженного изображения
        $resource = imagecreatetruecolor($newwidth, $newheight);
        imagecopyresampled($resource, $source, 0, 0, 0, 0, $newwidth, $newheight, $params[0], $params[1]);
        imagejpeg($resource, $resource_src, 80); //80 качество изображения
        
        //назначаем права доступа
        chmod("$source_src", 0644);
        chmod("$resource_src", 0644);
        
        //выводим сообщение
        $mess = '<center><br><p style="color:green;">Изображение загружено !</p></center>';
        $ok   = 1;
    }
}
?>
<center><br><h3>Загрузка аватара</h3></center>
<!--вывод сообщений--><?= $mess ?>
<?php
include("session.inc.php");
if (isset($_FILES['file'])) {
    $file = str_replace($server['DOCUMENT_ROOT'], '/', $path_mini . $username . "_" . $new_name); // получить путь вида '/img/avatars/15.jpg'
    mysql_query("UPDATE members SET avatar='$file' WHERE id='$userid';"); //Добавление в БД.
}
?>
<center><br>     
<p><form method="POST"  enctype="multipart/form-data" name='submit'>
<table id="upload1" ><tr><td>
</td> <td><span class="psevdoFile"><input id="psevdoFileValue" class="inputFileText"      value="выберете файл" style="color:#828282;" type="text"/>
<input class="fileInput" type="file" size="1" onchange="document.getElementById('psevdoFileValue').value = this.value" name="file"/>
</span></td></tr></tr>
</table> 

<table>
<tr><td><br><input type='submit' name='submit' class='pictures-btn' value='Загрузить'     style="cursor:pointer;border:0px;"/></a></td></tr>
</table></form></p>
</center>
```

Вот скрипт загрузки и создания миниатюр. Почему при загрузке некоторых изображений (голубой квадрат) выдается ошибка:

> `Warning: imagecreatetruecolor() [function.imagecreatetruecolor]: Invalid image dimensions in Z:\home\localhost\www\avatar\upload.php on line 58`
>
> `Warning: imagecopyresampled(): supplied argument is not a valid Image resource in Z:\home\localhost\www\avatar\upload.php on line 59`
>
> `Warning: imagejpeg(): supplied argument is not a valid Image resource in Z:\home\localhost\www\avatar\upload.php on line 60`
>
> `Warning: chmod() [function.chmod]: No error in Z:\home\localhost\www\avatar\upload.php on line 64`

Comment: Может быть стоит посмотреть как делают другие? В том же WP.. У Вас уже куча однотипных вопросов и все сводится к одному и тому же.
ЗЫ. А зачем собственные вопросы добавлять в закладки?

Comment: а зачем что то делать, если ширина равна высоте???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Англицким по белому же:

> > `Warning: imagecreatetruecolor() [function.imagecreatetruecolor]: Invalid image dimensions in Z:\home\localhost\www\avatar\upload.php on line 58`

Неправильный размер. Сделайте перед функцией `die(var_dump($newwidth, $newheight));` скорее всего, там либо дробные, либо отрицательные числа будут. Потом ищите, где они устанавливаются.

**UPDATE**

```
    //если высота больше ширины
    //вычисляем новую ширину
    if ($params[1] > $params[0]) {
        $newheight = 500;
        $newwidth  = floor($newheight * $params[0] / $params[1]);
    }
    //если ширина больше высоты
    //вычисляем новую высоту
    if ($params[1] < $params[0]) {
        $newwidth  = 500;
        $newheight = floor($newwidth * $params[1] / $params[0]);
    }
```

Замените на

```
    //если высота больше ширины
    //вычисляем новую ширину
    if ($params[1] > $params[0]) {
        $newheight = 500;
        $newwidth  = floor($newheight * $params[0] / $params[1]);
    } else {
        $newwidth  = 500;
        $newheight = floor($newwidth * $params[1] / $params[0]);
    }
```

Comment: При значении  $newwidth  = 500; и $newwidth  = 500; пишет:
int(500) float(335) а при загрузке рисунка (голубой квадрат) пишет: NULL NULL .Что с этими числами надо сделать, как то выровнять их или что ?

Comment: http://saveimg.ru/show-image.php?id=0a79889ec59d8c2c5259d3cbfdc9ac6c
Вот этот рисунок загружается но при создании миниатюры пишет:Warning: imagecreatetruecolor() [function.imagecreatetruecolor]: Invalid image dimensions in Z:\home\localhost\www\avatar\upload.php on line 58. А если через die то пишет NULL NULL.

Comment: Так правильно, у вас там "если ширина больше высоты, делать то-то, а если меньше - другое", а для равных у вас и нет ничего))

Comment: А че сделать, помогите пожалуйста :(

Comment: Обновил

Comment: Спасибо БОЛЬШОЕ !!! Все работает. Я к стати перед твоим ответом немного полазил.И у меня тоже все заработало когда я поставил в 
if($params[1]<=$params[0]) короче знак равно сработал.